# Understanding the resistance readings between PCB connectors

Tags: pcb, resistance, multimeter, short-circuit

Based on a [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/381440/how-to-test-for-shorts-on-a-breakout) I asked earlier today, I am trying to verify that there's not short caused by my bad soldering.

Luckily I had bought two of these modules.  To make a baseline, I started looking at the module that I had not done anything to.

Using this [Multimeter](http://www.extech.com/resources/MN30_UM-en.pdf) (on a disconnected module -- it has no solder and no wires in/out), I am pressing the black lead again the MOSI pin (see diagram below) and moving the red lead one pin down, one pin at a time.

However, I am not entirely sure what I am looking at, for example:

With black on MISO and red on MOSI, or SCK, the reading is **350+K Ohms**.

With the black on MISO and read on RESET, the reading is **150+K Ohms**.

With black on MISO and red on DIO5, the reading is **1.05K** Ohms and red on GND shows **0.5K** Ohms.

When I compare that with [this video](https://youtu.be/ln8OhK-wdFY?t=4m24s) for example, his reading stays at **1** across pin changes.

Again, this is an untouched board, direct from the seller.  So is my understanding not correct (i.e. the readings are fine and I don't know what they mean)?  Or is it a bad module?

[image]

Comment: Can you inspect visually ?

Comment: @LongPham What do you mean?

Comment: By visually, I mean eyeballing the board to check for any faulty copper or solder bridge.

Comment: The board looks fine, direct from seller, nothing visible to indicate a problem

Comment: If you have a short you will most likely get about 0 ohms.

Comment: I see, so what accounts for 350K vs 1k?

Comment: could be electrostatic damage.

Comment: Because there's stuff on the board, which has connections between the two pins, and you get bogus resistance measurements because it's not designed to have a particular resistance. That's generally what happens when you try to measure the resistance of ICs, diodes, transistors etc. It doesn't mean there's damage. The point is it isn't 0

Comment: The "1" you see on the video will be on the lowest resistance range, probably 200 ohms, or "continuity test", which usually sounds a buzzer below some value, 5 or 10 ohms. ALL your measurements are above 200 ohms so you'd see "1" on your 200 ohm range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of these are shorted, which is what you read when the DMM leads are connected to each other.

> With black on MISO and red on MOSI, or SCK, the reading is 350+K Ohms.

MOSI and CLK are both high R inputs as displayed

> With the black on MISO and read on RESET, the reading is 150+K Ohms.

Reset is high R input as displayed

> With black on MISO and red on DIO5, the reading is 1.05K Ohms

Both are low R outputs but not active? probably diode resistance

> and red on GND shows 0.5K Ohms.

Same as above

**Unless you wore a gnded ESD strap, they were not untouched**

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely fine. These kind of numbers are typical when there are components on the board. You might want to trace through and see what that 500R reading is - perhaps a resistor on the board. A short from bad soldering is generally pretty close to zero ohms.